# Is there a way to only skip the commit-msg hook

Tags: git, github, git-commit, pre-commit-hook

I've put a check for the commit message in the commit-msg hook which I want to skip at times. I know there is a `git commit --no-verify` for the task, but that also skips the pre-commit hook. Is there a way to only skip the commit-msg hook and not the pre-commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but also yes:

- *Git* does not provide a mechanism for this.
- But *Git* does not write the commit hooks.  *You* write the commit hooks.

So, write your commit-msg hook so that it checks for some sort of control knob: "if control knob is set one way, check the commit message; if it's set the other way, just accept the commit message".

Your task is now to pick the control knob and make sure it's set the right way at the right time.  One obvious possibility is a simple environment variable:

```
$ SKIP_MESSAGE_CHECK=yes git commit -m "silly message"
```

(assuming an sh/bash style shell; use `env SKIP_MESSAGE_CHECK=yes ...` if needed).